# Why an array of array preserves my initial array?

Tags: arrays, perl

So I have this fragment of code:

```
push @{$savedcallouts[-1]}, {
$funcnm => {
    matches => {%$captures},
    flags => [eval { @flags}]
}};
print Dumper \@{$savedcallouts[-1]};
```

Which gives the following result:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            {
              'normalexpr' => undef
            },
            {
              'normalexpr' => undef
            },
            {
              'ternaryexpr' => undef
            }
          ]
        ];
```

But if I remove the square brackets of `flags => [eval { @flags}]` (i.e. have `flags => eval { @flags}` - I get this:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'begin_binary' => {
                              'HASH(0x1038301c0)' => {
                                                       'ternaryexpr' => undef
                                                     },
                              'flags' => {
                                           'normalexpr' => undef
                                         },
                              'matches' => {}
                            }
        };
```

Any ideas why is this happening and how can I potentially avoid - i.e. have the array as hash field directly without artifacts or being an nested array.

Comment: Tip: `{%$captures}` can probably be reduced to `$captures`. No need to make a copy of the hash.

Comment: @ikegami Sometimes you would want to use a different copy of the hash. We recently had a Perl question where someone used the same reference and wondered why only the last value was saved.

Comment: @TLP, And the answer was probably "misplaced `my`", not use of `{%$captures}`. Yes, it's sometimes needed, but very rare. That's why I said "probably", but that was being quite generous. I should have said "almost guaranteed".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `eval { }` is useless here. `@flags` isn't going to throw any exceptions.<sup>[1]</sup>

So

```perl
flags => eval { @flags }
```

is a weird way of writing

```perl
flags => @flags
```

---

```perl
flags => @flags
```

is a shorthand for

```perl
"flags", @flags
```

which is

```perl
"flags", $flags[0], $flags[1], $flags[2], ...
```

which is

```perl
"flags"   => $flags[0],
$flags[1] => $flags[2],
...
```

---

> have the array as hash field directly

The values of hash elements are scalars.

You can store a reference to an array in a scalar, but you can't store an array in a scalar.

---

1. Well, it's possible to add magic to `@flags` that throws an exception when accessed. But would you really want to ignore this exception? I can't fathom why you used `eval` here.